# Can anyone identify what brand/company makes tracks for these curtains?

Tags: windows, hanging

There are snaps on each end and the plastic "hooks" run along the entire top. I need to purchase tracks for these, however, I can't find the company they are made from.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These appear to be [Ripple Fold](http://www.hunterdouglashospitality.com/channel/fabrication/ripplefold.jsp) curtains.

It is a proprietary system of curtains which allows for hanging a wide variety of fabrics without having to create gathers in the traditional way.